# Negative value for area

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I have a problem with the following example:Given the surfaces:$$x^2+y^2+z^2=5, x^2+z^2\ge (y-1)^2$$ find the area bounded with them. First problem appears when I try to sketch this in 3D. For the first one is sphere and that is OK, and the second one should be infinite cone right? (but not sure what part of it left or right, since it is on y axis).

Then for intersection I get $x^2+z^2=1$ and after cilindrical coordinates it is easy to see that $0\le r\le 1$ and $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$.
After that, I am calculating the area of cone and sphere seperatly. So for sphere i get $$\sqrt{5}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta \int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{rdr}{\sqrt{5-r^2}}$$. But this integral has a negative value, so I am obviously mistaking somewhere but not sure where.

BTW i used that $y=\sqrt{5-x^2-z^2}$ from the equation of sphere and than plugged that into formula.

Comment: The first equation is indeed a sphere, a surface, but the second equation is a "filled / solid cone", not a surface. Which **area** should be computed? Then the integral is definitively done on a positive function, so it is positive. (We cannot know how you obtained a negative value...)

Comment: The area between sphere and cone. So i need to find $P_1$(area of sphere) and $P_2$(area of cone) and to add the together. For integral, my bad.

Comment: Please note you will have two cones from the equation along $y-$axis, with vertex at $(0, 1, 0)$ and increasing radius as go up the $y-$ axis and one inverted cone as you go down the $y-$axis. There are two intersections of the solids, at $y = -1, 2$. Now it is confusing which bounded surface area the question seeks.

Comment: In fact based on the inequality sign it seems it seeks surface area of sphere bound between those two cones.

Comment: I'm not sure what $\ge$ is telling me which cone am I watching etc?

Comment: So is it correct to add the area of sphere and cone?

Comment: If it was seeking surface area bounded between each cone and the sphere, it would have said $x^2 + z^2 \leq (y-1)^2$. $\geq$ means it is outside the cones.

Comment: I get it, and should i correct something now?

Comment: No the surface area that you would see between the cones will only be of the sphere.

Comment: BTW: while your integral is far from the realities of this problem, it has a positive integrand, so how could it ever be negative?

Comment: If the surface area is only sphere, than the final integral is solution right? For the integral my bad, sorry.

Comment: @MilicaKoprivica No it is not correct. Please see the $2$D sketch I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to do it in spherical coordinates.

Your integral should be

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{cos^{-1}({\frac{2}{\sqrt5}})}^{\pi - cos^{-1}({\frac{1}{\sqrt5}})} 5 \sin \phi \, d\phi \, d\theta$

If you see from top ($z-$ axis) in $XY$ plane, this is how the projection looks. This sketch helps to understand the limits of integral.

[image]

EDIT: also given you were doing it in cylindrical coordinates, here is the integral in cylindrical coordinates with the correct limits. Please note $-1 \leq y \leq 2$ so you will have to split the integral into two parts, one for surface area above $XZ$ plane and one for below it. For $y = -1, r = 2 \,$ and for $\, y = 2, r = 1$

For above: $\displaystyle \sqrt{5} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{1}^{\sqrt 5}\frac{r}{\sqrt{5-r^2}} \, dr \, d\theta$

For below: $\displaystyle \sqrt{5} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{2}^{\sqrt 5}\frac{r}{\sqrt{5-r^2}} \, dr \, d\theta$

Comment: And pls let me know if you have questions.

Comment: $S=6 \sqrt{5} \pi\approx 13.4\%$ of the sphere is too small, looking at he actual plot of the surface

Comment: @Raffaele this is correct. I think you mistook the radius.

Comment: We got the same result... thank you for the correction. I've always been quite *clumsy*...

Comment: We all have those moments! :)

Comment: Just saw this, sorry. OK, my bad, I also got $y=2, y=-1$ but for some reason i canceled $y=-1$ :). I have questions, first we got upper bound $r=\sqrt{5}$ when we set $y=0$ right? And I add these two volumes at the end right? My main problem is to sketch and read from the picutre :(.

Comment: That is correct. You get upper bound of $r$ for $y = 0$. Yes you add both surface areas. You are basically discarding the surface area that is above  $y = 2$ or below $y = -1$. The reason - for those points on the surface $x^2 + y^2 \leq (y-1)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+y^2+z^2=5$ and $ x^2+z^2= (y-1)^2$ intersect at

$y^2+(y-1)^2=5\to y_1=-1;\;y_2$

The surface is in the picture below and its area is $S=2\pi rh$.

where $r=\sqrt 5$ is the radius of the sphere, $h$ is the height $h=|y_2-y_1|=|2-(-1)|=3$

Therefore $$S=6\sqrt 5\pi$$
which is $67\%$ of the area of the sphere $20\pi$

[image]

Comment: Radius is $\sqrt 5$ and not $5$.

Comment: @MathLover Thank you!